# Where should I ask a question about a Bluetooth connection of a phone with a car?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question regarding the Bluetooth connection of a mobile phone with a car. It's an older car, so nothing related to Android Auto is relevant, even though the phone is an Android.

[Super User](https://superuser.com) is not an appropriate site because they list that the questions should not be about mobile devices. I also don't quite feel like it belongs to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) because my question has nothing to do with programming or software development.

Maybe to help frame it better, here is my actual problem: I have an Android phone and an older car from 2011 which allows you to pair the phone via Bluetooth for calls, but not for anything else. I want to find a way to bypass this and to play music in my car via Bluetooth without using one of these aux-to-Bluetooth converters because my aux port is in the glove box and it's very inconvenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) since it has a [bluetooth tag](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth).

Before deciding if you should ask there, take a look at the types of Bluetooth questions to see if yours is similar.